# Does not being approved for an Amazon store credit card impact credit score?

Tags: credit-card, credit-score

I just applied for "Amazon Prime Rewards Visa Card" as I do lot of Amazon Shopping. But I received the below message after submitting my application:

***Thank you for Applying.
Unfortunately, your application for the Amazon Prime Rewards Visa card could not be approved by _____.***

***___ Will notify you in writing about the decision in 30 days. Thank you for applying.***

I do not have any credit history. I am assuming that could be the reason. I was recently approved for another credit card.

But does this not approved status have any impact on my credit score?

Comment: Be sure to read the letter you get from Chase. They may offer the opportunity to contact them to have your application reviewed/reconsidered (by a person, not a computer) if your's is an edge case.

Comment: @CactusCake +1 on this.  I've been declined before simply because I used a new address that wasn't yet on my credit report.  It's worth the effort to talk to the reconsideration people.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Getting rejected for a credit card does not impact your credit score.

However, applying for a credit card, whether or not you are approved, does impact your score temporarily.  Each time your credit report is accessed by a creditor, an "inquiry" instance appears on your credit report.  These inquiries stay on your credit report for two years, although [it is reported](http://www.bankrate.com/finance/credit-cards/how-long-does-credit-check-affect-score.aspx) that the inquiries only affect your FICO credit score for one year.